# it is possible to embed a private report into a web site & filtering access to data for non G users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

We're trying to embed a GDS private report in our customer portal and we hope to filter the data using the email of the person connected to our customer portal . some of our users are no google users (they dont have an account gmail) and they're connected to this portal with an email and password form of authentification.

Our data is stored in Google Storage and we use Bigquery for querying and we use BQ connector to connect BQ and Google Data Studio.

There is any solution to do this ? parameters in GDS report URL ? Through API?

Any help will be appreciated.

Taoufiq.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7450249?hl=en&ref_topic=7442437) states that the only sharing options are: a) Making the report public, or b) Have the user authenticate with a google account. Unfortunately, it neither has an API, nor support for parameters through URL yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do using Community Connectors and some minor development work in your portal. You will need to pass a short lived unique token as a parameter for the embedded report and then have an API or some other way to tie that token to a user identity. This [solution guide](http://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials) has instructions for this specific use case.

Comment: As far as I understand Community Connectors is for collecting data for creating datastudio report... Report is already there we need to share that report to people who does not have gsuite id and we do not want to make sharing option enable with "Anyone with link" can view it

Comment: 1. I wouldn't say Community Connectors is for collecting data - it lets you create your own data pipeline and build in your own business logic into the connector. 

2. Unfortunately, what you are requesting is not possible to do at present (Apr 2021) without the method I mentioned. We specifically came up with this method since this was a highly requested feature. 3. Since you control the connector logic, you should ensure that connector does not leak any data when presented with any invalid (including null) token. That would mitigate risks from exposing the dashboard to anyone with link.

Comment: Thank you Minaz ... You mean to say that report will still be sharable anyone with link but it will only show data when there is valid token for valid user right ?

Comment: What i was hoping for was to have one Gsuite account which will be fetch report on behalf of third party authenticated user and the report is shared with only that one Gsuite account

Comment: 1) "report will still be sharable ... valid token for valid user" > Correct - you will have to add that logic in your connector code. 2) " ... have one Gsuite account which will be fetch report on behalf of third party authenticated user..." - That is the exact logic built into the connector code in this approach. Instead of this being applied to the report, this will be applied to the data source. And instead of a G Suite account, you will use a service account to fetch the data. I suggest reviewing the sample code.

Comment: @MinhazKazi - I also want to be able to embed reports within the website to authenticated users, but don't need to filter the report, I just need to stop people with the report link being able to view the report outside of the application. Do you have a tutorial on YouTube that details how you'd set a connector up to do this? I know you've detailed it via a solution article, but as someone who's never even touched a connector before its still a bit unclear (sorry). All the report data comes from BigQuery directly, it doesn't come via a connector into the website. (If that matters). thx

Comment: @SteveChilds - Just share the report with the whole org. No additional steps should be necessary for your use case.

Comment: @MinhazKazi - how do I share the report with the organisation, we're on Office, not Google, i.e. no work google accounts.